# OS Sierra update corrupted $PATH, .bash_profile, .bashrc

Tags: restore, macos

Sierra update corrupted `$PATH`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and many others. Is this a common issue? Is there any way to get those files/settings back (I don't have a backup)? In the past I often installed new OSs and everything was fine.

Comment: If you do not have a backup then you'll have to manually recreate the information within the files. There is no good excuse for not maintaining regular backups and especially a backup before a major upgrade!

Comment: Sierra doesn't install ~/.bash* files. Please post the content of the files if they are not just garbage (JSK|[™Ω  G<b etc.)

Comment: Off-topic but one suggestion to prevent is to setup a git repository preferably on github, and add those dot files inside the repo, and symlink it back to $HOME, so you always have a backup of those configs.

Comment: I suggest to change your question title for a question. For example "How to analyze a PATH misbehaviour?". You might get more appropriate help.